# UWP 10 and Windows 8 or 8.1

Tags: uwp

Is it possible to install uwp 10 applications on windows 8 or 8.1? I tried to install it from bundle on win10 and it works, on win 8.1 I have an error: 0x80080204. The Appx package's manifest is invalid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excerpt from the [official requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx) to develop a Windows 10 app:

> ***Windows 8.1 and Windows 7 support***
>   If you choose to develop Universal Windows apps with Visual Studio 2015 on a platform other than Windows 10, these are the restrictions:
>   - **Windows 8.1**: You can’t run the app locally (only on a remote Windows 10 device). You can use the emulators in Visual Studio, but not the simulator.
>   - Windows 7: You can’t run the app locally (only on a remote Windows 10 device). You can’t use the emulators or the simulator in Visual Studio either.

Neither a developer, nor any normal user can run Windows 10 apps on Windows 8(.1) or 7.

Answer (score 1):

No, It is not possible, because UWP apps are not backward compatible. Windows 10 can run Windows 8/8.1 apps but not vice versa.